# Nougot (android 7) status bar in lock screen

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I have installed android 7 and now i want to i have problem with showing status bar while my phone is lock.
by showing status bar any one can use the phone easily as using the guest mode or any thing else. i also want to remove the camera shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable that users option

1. Go to settings
2. Click Users
3. Click Menu Icon
4. Untick Add users when device locked if you don't want adding users from lock screen.

[image]

To disable camera icon at lock

1. Go to Settings
2. Click on Lockscreen
3. Click Lockscreen shortcuts and remove the camera icon or replace it with another app

[image]